# Find the pairs $(x,y) ; 0 \le x,y \le 18$ such that $19 \vert 3x+4y+5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $\mathrm S ={(a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb Z,  0\le a,b \le 18}$. Find the number of elements in $\mathrm S$ such that $3x+4y+5$ is divisible by $19$.

I tried using congruences to simplify the problem.

We need $$3x+4y \equiv -5 \pmod{19} \equiv 14 \pmod{19}$$

I wrote $3x+4y \equiv 3(2)+4(2) \pmod{19}$. But I am not able to conclude anything from this. I know that if we find $(x,y)$ such that $x  \equiv 2 \pmod {19}, y \equiv 2 \pmod{19}$ will satisfy the criteria, but will only these? I am stuck here. Please help me with proceeding in this solution
or any other solution will also work.

Thanks!

Comment: If $(a,b)$ is in $S$, then $(a+7,b-2)$ is also in $S$. So $S$ is either empty or it has inifinitely many elements.

Comment: @user340297 $3\cdot 7-4\cdot 2=21-8=13$ is not divisible by $19$. Also notice $0\le a,b\le 18$.

Comment: They are $19$ $$(0,\,13),\,(1,\,17),\,(2,\,2),\,(3,\,6),\,(4,\,10),\,(5,\,14),\,(6,\,18),\,(7,\,3),\,(8,\,7),\,(9,\,11),\,(10,\,15),\,(11,\,0),\,(12,\,4),\,(13,\,8),\,(14,\,12),\,(15,\,16),\,(16,\,1),\,(17,\,5),\,(18,\,9)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $19$ is a prime, we have

$$\begin{align}
3x+4y+5\equiv0\mod19
&\iff15x+20y+25\equiv0\mod19\\
&\iff-4x+y+6\equiv0\mod19\\
&\iff y\equiv4x-6\mod19
\end{align}$$

Hence each value of $x$ from $0$ to $18$ gives precisely one value of $y$ in the same range, e.g., $x=15\implies y\equiv54\equiv16$ mod $19$.  So there are precisely $19$ elements of $S$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: Great +1..........

Answer (score 1):

Write $3x+4y+5=19z$

First we see that $1\leq z\leq 6$. Since $3\mid 19z-4y-5$ we have $3\mid z-y+1$ and so $z-y+1 = 3t$ for some integer $t$. From here we get:

\begin{eqnarray}
y&=& z-3t+1\\
x&=& 4t+5z-3
\end{eqnarray}
So 
\begin{eqnarray}
0\leq& z-3t+1& \leq 18\\
0\leq & 4t+5z-3&\leq 18
\end{eqnarray}

**Case 1**: $z=1$ then $t= 0$ so $1$ solution $x= 2$ and $y=2$.

**Case 2**: $z=2$ then $-2\leq t\leq 1$ so $4$ solution.

**Case 3**: $z=3$ then $?\leq t\leq ?$ so $?$ solution.

...

Answer (score 1):

$$
3x+4y \equiv 14 \pmod{19} 
$$

To find a solution we start by searching for a solution of
$$
3x \equiv 1 \pmod{19}\\
4y \equiv 1 \pmod{19}
$$
A solution is given by $x_0=13,y_0=5$. Then the solution of the original modular equation is given by:
$$
x\equiv tx_0 \pmod{19}, \qquad y\equiv (14-t)y_0 \pmod{19},
$$
for $0 \leq t\leq 18$. See [relevant post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435455/how-to-solve-axby-c-mod-p).

For example for $t=0$ we get the pair $(0,13)$ as a solution and for $t=1$ we get $(13,8)$. Can you continue from here?

$$
t=0 \rightarrow (0,13)\\
t=1 \rightarrow (13,8)\\
t=2 \rightarrow (7,3)\\
t=3 \rightarrow (1,17)\\
\dots\\
$$